# sql for copying a table

Tags: sql

I have a table 'table1' in   'database1'.

Now i wants to create a table 'table2' in 'database2', with the exact data from 'table1'

How can i do that with **select into**  query

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * INTO table2 IN database2 FROM table1`

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention your SQL dialect, but this is how you would do it on SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
INTO   database2..table2
FROM   database1..table1
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't use a select into, that's for setting variables (with mysql anyway).

```
create table table2 as
select * from table1
```

Note that this doesn't copy indexes or anything, and the typical lecture about having a bad schema.

Comment: dont ofrget to qualify the table names with the database like database1.table1